# Unattended_Windows_Update state.apply missing two points

Tags: yaml, salt, salt-creation

Good Day Salt-Community,

i am currently trying to make a simply salt state that just allows for unattended windows updates.
i wanted it to do more than just that for example i want it to create a log.file just for the state itself and also have a 15 sec delay after each and every machine.

`update_system: wua.uptodate`

thats what i understood but how to make it do the other two things, i cant get the hang of it.
Using the `--log-file=/path/to/file` in addition to the state apply command creates the log but is there a way to make it via the state itself?

I tried to get a hint of the right syntax but other than the simple update_system i cant get anything else to work the way i want within the state.

i get the Windows system up to date, thats what is inside of my .sls
I get a log but only via the log-file cmd-line addition not via the state itself
I am completely clueless how to get a delay of any kind between the machines.